# Any way to map an open() call on a unix socket to a socket() and connect() call?

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm wondering whether there is a way to make it such that someone can write to my UNIX socket by simply calling open() on a file and writing to it?  As it stands now they have to do something like the following:

```
// Create socket.

fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd == -1)
    {
    result = -1;
    goto done;
    }

// Set socket name.

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_name, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1);

// Connect.

result = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
if (result == -1)
    {

    // If some error then we're done.                                       
    }

// Write buffer.

result = write(fd, buffer, length);
if (result == -1)
    goto done;

close(fd);
```

I was hoping there might some mechanism where I could treat the socket file like an ordinary file and have users just call open(), write() and close().  Any such mechanism exist?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: No, it's not possible. Search the web for "unix socket shell" for examples that show that using standard functions/tools won't work on unix sockets

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. Are you designing a kernel module? Are you writing a library? What do you mean by "my UNIX socket" exactly?

Comment: David Schwartz - I've written a UNIX (Domain) socket server which clients use for logging, similar I guess to syslog.  I was thinking it would be nice if the client could simply do: fopen(), fprintf(), fclose() instead of making the socket calls followed by a write() and close().

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's possible with FUSE, but you're better off using `socat` or even a more-specific solution.